# ¿Cómo colocar mensaje cuando los inputs estan vacios, tipo required?

Tags: javascript

como hacer para que las tabs se detenga cuando hay campos vacios que impida el avance de las tabs
una vez llenado los campos que porcierto tienen required, pero no me funciona no se detienen las tabs
si tengo en el paso 1 campos vacios impedir que se pueda dar next y llegar a paso 2
si tengo en el paso 2 auque sea un input vacio impedir llegar al paso 3
nose como hacer eso que estoy pidiendo
En la misma página tengo varias secciones. llamada uno , dos y tres
impedir el avance del boton next cuando hayan campos vacios
el boton deberia estar desabilitado una vez llenado todos los campos habilitarse y hacer lo mismo en la tabs 2 que este desabilitado y cuando se llenen tosos los campos llenados habilitarlo para ir a la seccion 3

**solo falta el mensaje de los inputs vacios, tipo required, pero quiero** **colocar mensaje personalizado**

```js
class TabbedContent {
          constructor() {
            this.tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".nav li");
            this.sections = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
            this.nextButton = document.querySelector("#nextBtn");
            this.prevButton = document.querySelector("#prevBtn");
            this.current = 0;
            const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[required]');
    inputs.forEach(input => {
        input.addEventListener('input', () => this.validateInputs());
    });
          }
          validateInputs() {
    const inputs = this.sections[this.current].querySelectorAll('input[required]');
    let allFilled = true;
    
    inputs.forEach(input => {
        if (!input.value) {
            allFilled = false;
        }
    });
    
    if (allFilled) {
        this.nextButton.classList.remove("disable");
    } else {
        this.nextButton.classList.add("disable");
    }
}
          toggleTabs() {
            this.tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
              tab.classList.remove('active');
            });
            this.tabs[this.current].classList.add("active");
          }
    
          toggleSections() {
            this.sections.forEach(function(section) {
              section.classList.remove('active');
            });
            this.sections[this.current].classList.add("active");
          }
    
          togglePrev() {
            const method = this.current == 0 ? 'add' : 'remove';
            this.prevButton.classList[method]("disable");
          }
    
          toggleNext() {
            const method = this.current == this.tabs.length - 1 ? 'add' : 'remove';
            this.nextButton.classList[method]("disable");
          }
    
          goNext() {
            if (this.current < this.tabs.length - 1 && !this.nextButton.classList.contains("disable")) {
        this.current++
            }
            this.toggleTabs();
            this.toggleSections();
            this.toggleNext();
            this.togglePrev();
            this.validateInputs();
          }
    
          goPrev() {
            if (this.current > 0) {
              this.current--
            }
            this.toggleTabs();
            this.toggleSections();
            this.toggleNext();
            this.togglePrev();
            this.validateInputs();
          }
    
        }
    
        const tabbedContent = new TabbedContent();
        tabbedContent.validateInputs(); //
```

```css
.container {
          max-width: 600px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          text-align: center;
        }
    
        .section {
          display: none;
        }
    
        .section.active {
          display: block;
        }
    
        ul {
          list-style: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
        }
    
        ul li {
          background: #ccc;
          padding: 10px 15px;
          margin-left: 6px;
          border-radius: 50%;
          cursor: pointer;
          opacity: .5;
        }
    
        ul li.active {
          opacity: 1 !important;
        }
    
        .next,
        .previous {
          padding: 15px 10px;
          border-radius: 6px;
          background: deepskyblue;
          color: white;
          border: 0;
          outline: none;
          cursor: pointer;
          width: 100px;
        }
    
        .next.disable,
        .previous.disable {
          cursor: none;
          opacity: .5;
        }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active">1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
          </ul>
    
    
  

            <section class="section section-one active">
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
       minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
       minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
       minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
       minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">

              </section>
              <section class="section section-two">
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
       minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
       minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
       minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">

          </section>
          <section class="section section-three">
            <h2>section 3</h2>
          </section>
    
    
          <button class="previous disable" id="prevBtn" onclick="tabbedContent.goPrev()">Previous</button>
          <button class="next" id="nextBtn" onclick="tabbedContent.goNext()">Next</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hola Felipe, puedes hacerlo sin  deshabilitar los botones, en la función que es llamada por el botón, lo primero que haces, es recorrer con un for, los campos involucrados, y si encuentra alguno vacío, que imprima un aviso y haga un return.

Comment: nose como hacerlo con este codigo puedes hacerlo en mi ejemplo, porfavor